# Showing only things belonging to a selected user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a list of things users have created, and I am having trouble showing them based on who created them.

In my view I have

```
  <%= form_tag({}, class: "form-inline") do %>
    <%= label_tag("user_names", "Users") %>
    <%= text_field_tag("user_names", params[:user_names]) %>
```

And then in my controller I am trying to scope it with this

```
    if params[:user_names].present?
      @random = @random.where(:user_id => :user_names)
```

I see the dropdown, but I'm trying to get is so the dropdown shows the users names and lets me select one, so that when I submit the form, I only see entries associated with that user.

What am I missing?

Comment: Will a user's ID ever be equal to a user's name? Right now you're setting the query to check :user_id against the symbol `:user_names`, it is unlikely this is what you want.

Comment: Well I was hoping that I could show their name, and then search by the id associated with the name, which is stored in the objects as user_id

Comment: You can, but you need to pass in user IDs, not the symbol `:user_names`.

Comment: So how can I go about doing that?

Comment: Create a select box where the value is the id, and the text is the user name.

Comment: I'm not sure how to format it, right now I have `<%= select_tag("employee_names", params[:employee_names]) %>` and anytime I try to change or add anything, I get an error that it is taking to many arguments.

Comment: There are actually docs for `select_tag`, but obviously you'd need to pass it a collection of employee id/name pairs generated either in the controller, or directly in the view.

Comment: I guess that is where I am stuck, I read the documents and API stuff but either I was reading it wrong or something because I kept getting errors. So I guess I need to make a method in the controller that returns all of the employee names? If I do that how to I fill the select tag with them and associate that with the ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the users by username and join in the other model through the user association.

```
if params[:user_names].present?
  @random = @random.joins(:user).where("users.username IN (?)", params[:usernames])
end
```

Comment: Awesome, is there a way I can change the view so that it lists all of the users by user.name and I can select one of them, and it searches by user.id like you gave me?